# token в url

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Сейчас у меня в url: http://suite/index.php?users&id=4, думаю пояснить не нужно. Недавно наткнулся на такую технологию url:  http://suite/index.php?tkn=9e184f09378a891552fa7b0c0686b336, причём выполняет он такую же функцию как и у меня. Как  реализовать такой tkn у себя на сайте и зачем он нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие токены обычно даются пользователю при авторизации.
Не самый удобный способ, т.к. придется все url-ы генерировать с учетом токена

Answer (score 1):

Я не думаю, что Вам на сайте он нужен. Токен использую для аторизации, и чаще всего он временный.